# laravel: withCount return me column not found exception

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I defined a scope function in an Eloquent model that uses withCount in the query, I also define an unit test for this function that works properly but when I use it in my controller it throws the exception error which is

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'unused_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `coupons` where  `unused_count` > 0)
```

Here are my eloquent model functions:

```
public function unsed(): BelongsToMany
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_coupon')
            ->wherePivot('discount', '=', 0);
}

public function scopeAvailable(Builder $query): Builder
{
        return $query->where(function ($coupons) {
            return $coupons
                ->withCount('unused')
                ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
                ->orWhere('unused_count', '>', 0 );
        });
}
```

Comment: `withCount` expect you to pass a relationship, not a column, is `unused_count` a relationship? also please add more details so people can help

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I used the same code for unit testing and it worked

Comment: Are you actually using `unused_count` anywhere else? If you are, then what you have is fine, but if not, you can simply do `->orHas('unused')`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence. That will only return records that have at least 1 record returned for the `unused` relationship.

Comment: Thank u @TimLewis, The problem arises because I want to put a relation inside another where clauses, which seems impossible. However, I got the following answer that works for me!

Comment: Yeah, `->where()` doesn't typically work on relationships, that's what the `->has()`/`->whereHas()` methods are for  I'd have to see what you mean, but yes, the solution you have is also fine; I was just curious if that other approach would work for you, since it's slightly shorter/cleaner. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I got what you mention my friend that is cleaner approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it related to `where` clause in my codes so I use `having` like below:

```
public function scopeAvailable(Builder $query): Builder
{
        return $query->where(fn($coupons) => $coupons
           ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
           ->orHas('Unused')
        );
}
```

I think the reason is that withCount / with clauses using select with groupBy under the hood which makes sense as here [having vs where](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj1ovzX_fT7AhWZjaQKHfM0AFwQFnoECBAQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaravelplug.com%2Fmysql-having-vs-where%2F%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DDifference%2520between%2520%25E2%2580%259CWHERE%25E2%2580%259D%2520and%2520%25E2%2580%259C%2CSELECT%2520statement%2520without%2520GROUP%2520BY.&usg=AOvVaw291aEpLT0HmIqrm5eoLY5a) has described it.